# Symfony forms entity type with custom optgroup

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have a Symfony form with select boxes that lists down its options from an entity. But how can I list the database records (options) inside an `<optgroup>` which I manually specify (label of the optgroup)?

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
        'required' => true, 
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Types', 
        'choice_label' => 'name', 
        'empty_value' => 'Type',
    ));
```

The optgroup label is "What is the Type?" and I need to list the above data inside this optgroup.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by using the group_by option:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
        'required' => true, 
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Types', 
        'choice_label' => 'name', 
        'empty_value' => 'Type',
        'group_by' => 'group',
));
```

You should add a field to AppBundle:Types which is named for example 'group'.

Comment: I would suggest to update your answer by explaining that `group_by` can be a callable, so you may define your custom way to group without adding any field. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by

Answer (score 0):

If this is a simple translation of a static string, I suggest you manually wrap your fields in an `optgroup` in your view (you could use a form theme for example), and set the label with your translated string. It would make more sense in my opinion.

If the label is dynamic, then I think this is what you're looking for : 
[Symfony Doctrine - how to generate optgroup select form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798180/symfony-doctrine-how-to-generate-optgroup-select-form)